# Page.BottomAppBar not being refreshed with NavigationCacheMode enabled

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

Here is my current App flow in a windows phone 8.1:

- I have a MainPage with a Pivot and a BottomAppBar
- Pivot Item content is populated using the above code in MainPage:

```cs
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RootPivot.Items == null) return;
        RootPivot_OnPivotItemLoaded(RootPivot, new PivotItemEventArgs { Item = RootPivot.Items[RootPivot.SelectedIndex] as PivotItem });
    }

    private void RootPivot_OnPivotItemLoaded(Pivot sender, PivotItemEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Item.Content == null) args.Item.Content = CreateUserControlForPivotItem((string)args.Item.Header, sender);

        var content = args.Item.Content as UserControl;
        if (content == null || content.DataContext == null)
        {
            BottomAppBar.DataContext = null;
            return;
        }

        BottomAppBar.DataContext = null;
        BottomAppBar.DataContext = content.DataContext;

        var viewModel = content.DataContext as IRefreshableViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null) viewModel.Refresh();
    }

    private static UserControl CreateUserControlForPivotItem(string pivotItemHeader, Pivot pivot)
    {
        UserControl item = null;
        switch (pivotItemHeader)
        {
            case "Appointments":
                item = new AppointmentsPivotItem();
                break;

            case "Profile":
                item = new ProfilePivotItem();
                break;
        }

        return item;
    }
```

each UserControl has a ViewModel as DataContext, which is responsible of handling the BottomAppBar:

```xml
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="BottomAppBar" Foreground="#FFFEFEFE" Background="{StaticResource BlueColorBrush}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=RequiresBottomAppBar, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="{Binding AppBarButtonAdd}" Command="{Binding AppBarButtonAddCommand}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=RequiresAppBarButtonAdd, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="{Binding AppBarButtonFind}" Command="{Binding AppBarButtonFindCommand}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=RequiresAppBarButtonFind, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"></AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

On the AppointmentsPivotItem I have a ListView and the problem begins when I try to navigate back from an Item details page back to the list.
MainPage has `NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"` and the binding for the AppBar is being called when navigated back, however, it does not appear until I navigate againg through Pivot items.

Can you please suggest an work around?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after 1 day I suddenly came to a solution that will do the trick.
Somehow, a call to `BottomAppBar.UpdateLayout()` before setting its `DataContext` will force the bar to redraw accordingly to the binding.

Hope this will help someone.